# Why does $\sqrt[4]{-2}=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt[4]{2}}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, radicals, roots-of-unity

When I type $\sqrt[4]{-2}$ into WolframAlpha, it lists $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt[4]{2}}$ as an alternate form. How did it get that? I was trying to solve for $x^{4}+2=0$, and so I guess I could just say $\sqrt[4]{-2}$ is a solution, but I want it to look like $a+bi$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

I remember that the 4th roots of unity are $e^{\frac{2\pi k}{4}i}$ for $k=1,2,3,4$, but we want to get $-2$, not $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could try writing $-2$ in polar form. Explicitly
\begin{equation}
 - 2 = 2 e^{i \pi}.
\end{equation}
Now taking the fourth root,
\begin{equation*}
 (-2)^{1/4} = 2^{1/4}(e^{i \pi})^{1/4}.
\end{equation*}
Can you take it from there?

Comment: We could also try to read the question.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I'm not sure what you mean... As far as I can see we are just a few steps from obtaining $(-2)^{1/4} = (1+i)/(2^{1/4})$...

Comment: To me, it looks like a doubt that the result of WA is true. But title and body don't exactly coincide, so it may be a misunderstanding on my side, too.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt[4]2} = \frac1{\sqrt[4]{2}} + \frac1{\sqrt[4]{2}}i$, so while it isn't written on the form $a+bi$, it is really easy to transform it so that it is.

As for why $\sqrt[4]{-2}$ is given as that number, try raising $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt[4]2}$ to the fourth power, trudge through the arithmetic and you *will* get $-2$.

If you are wondering how to solve such a problem on your own, I would suggest doing it geometrically, in polar coordinates (although it's entirely possible to do without writing any powers of $e$). We want a number with an argument which is a quarter of the argument of $-2$. The argument of $-2$ is $\pi$, so $\frac\pi4$ will do. (Thinking back to the $a+bi$ form, this just means that $a = b$, and they're both positive.)

Next we need the length to be the fourth root of the length of $-2$. The length of $-2$ is $2$, so the length of our fourth root must be $\sqrt[4]{2}$. This means that $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} = \sqrt[4]2$, or since $a = b$, $2a^2 = \sqrt2$.

Solving this we get $a = b = \frac1{\sqrt[4]2}$, and there is our solution.

Now, don't forget that any non-zero complex number has *four* fourth roots, so you really need to find the other three. The implicit assumption that $\sqrt[k]{\hphantom x}$ gives a single answer is a big reason why I (and many others) don't like to use the symbol when dealing with complex numbers. In fact, even defining $i$ as $i = \sqrt{-1}$ is wrong in my opinion. It should be $i^2 = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

Although polar form is by far a better way to compute complex roots, you can try this for this problem:

A fourth root of $-2$ is a square root of $\pm\sqrt 2 i$.

Say that

$$(a+ib)^2=\pm\sqrt 2i$$

Then, taking real and imaginary parts respectively,

$$a^2-b^2=0$$
$$2ab=\pm\sqrt 2$$

Solve the system for $a$ and $b$ and you should find the Wolfram's solution (and three more). Note that this system is actually *two* systems, because of the $\pm$ sign.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\right)^4=\frac{(1+i)^4}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)^4=\frac{4}{2}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^4=2\left(\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{4}\right)\right)^4=$$

$$=2\exp(i\pi)=2*(-1)=-2$$
I've used these:

- $$\exp\left(\frac{i\pi}{4}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$$
- $$\exp(i\pi)=\cos(\pi)+i\sin(\pi)=-1$$

As [@DonAntonio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/31254/donantonio) pointed it out in the comments, it's much easier this way:
$$\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt[4]{2}}\right)^4=\frac{1}{2}(1+i)^4=\frac{1}{2}((1+i)^2)^2=\frac{1}{2}(1^2+2i+i^2)^2=\frac{(2i)^2}{2}=-2$$

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that this only gives the **principal** value – since the $n$th root of complex number has $n$ complex roots, then this is only *one* of the values of $(-2)^{1/4}$.

That being said, rearranging your equation gives $(-2)^{1/4} \cdot 2^{1/4} = 1+i$. When you take powers in polar form, you take the *powers* of the lengths and multiply the angles (from De Moivre's theorem); so when you take roots, you take the *roots* of the lengths and *divide* the angles.

Using this,  $-2$ has $r = 2$ and $\theta = \pi$, so the principal value of $(-2)^{1/4}$ has $r = -2$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$. Similarly, $2^{1/4}$ has $r=2^{1/4}$ and $\theta = 0$. Therefore, using polar multiplication $(r = 2^{1/4}, \theta = \frac{\pi}{4}) \cdot (r = 2^{1/4}, \theta =0)$ has $r = 2^{1/2}, \theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$; which is $1+i$ in Cartesian form.

Comment: I find it pretty cumbersome and annoying to have the angles measured in degrees instead of radians...and also that symbol $\;\angle\;$ adds to the confusion...

Comment: The notation $x \ \angle \ y$ means a number in polar form that has modulus $x$ and argument $y$. I figured this would be better than constantly saying 'a number with modulus $x$ and argument $y$', but if this adds to the confusion I might as well go with the longer way.

Comment: Then perhaps you should *explain* that notation, which I find pretty confusing, as it doesn't seem to be a standard one and itcrashes with the way more standard notation for angle...

Answer (score 0):

This equality is $75\%$ wrong.

Any non-zero complex number has exactly four fourth roots, and $z$ is one of them then the others are given by $z\zeta_4^k$ where $\zeta_4=e^{2i\pi/4}$ and $k=0, 1, 2, 3$.

Therefore the left-hand side does not represent one number without ambiguity, but **four**. You can check that the right-hand side is **one** of them (*). Indeed, due to the convention that the root of a positive real number is a positive real number, the form of the right-hand side implies that a choice was made.

(*) in the sense that, when raised to the fourth power, it gives $-2$.

Comment: I think $\sqrt[4]{-2}$ represents only 1 number, the principal 4th root of $-2$.

Comment: @Botond what would that mean?

Comment: @Botond There is no such thing as "principal 4th root" of a complex number. There is a "principal 4th root" of a *positive real* number, but $-2$ is not positive.

Comment: $-2=2\exp(i\pi)$, so it's principal 4th root is $\left(2\exp(i\pi)\right)^{1/4}=2^{1/4}\exp\left(\frac{i \pi}{4}\right)$

Comment: @Botond Also $-2=2\exp(3i\pi)$ and $-2=2\exp(-i\pi)$ etc. Which one do you prefer? Wikipedia, somehow confusingly (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root), says "A complimentary definition of principal root (*though not formally defined or universally accepted*) is to say that it is always the complex root that has the least value of the argument among all roots; here “argument” means the counterclockwise angle in radians between the positive real axis and the line joining the complex number to the origin." (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: @Botond (Cont'd) Why isn't it universally accepted? Because it invokes an arbitrary convention that the argument is in the range $[0,2\pi)$ - in many applications it is convenient to take the argument from a different set $[\alpha, \alpha+2\pi)$, you will see that a lot in complex analysis.

Comment: @user8734617 I prefer the one I mentioned. Isn't that one the "compatible" with positive numbers?

Comment: @Botond there is not "one" choice compatible with reals. Just like there is not "one" choice of extension of the logarithm. You can see it more clearly on $\sqrt{x}=e^{\frac12 \ln(x)}$.

Comment: @user8734617 Do you prefer to treat $\sqrt[a]{b}$ as $\sqrt[a]{b}:=\{x|x^a=b\}$?

Comment: @Botond I personally prefer to not write $\sqrt[a]b$ for complex numbers, at all. Or I would indicate clearly what I mean everytime I have to do so.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier To be honest, I don't even remember what did I mean by ""compatible" with positive numbers". I think I wanted to say compatible with the principal value of the $\log$ function, since the principal value of $\exp^{-1}(-1)=i\pi$

Comment: @ArnaudMortier That's a good idea too, but it might be useful in a lot of cases to treat it as I've mentioned above.